# Assume that $ G = MC $, for some cyclic subgroup $ C $. Is $ M \cap C $ a normal subgroup of $ G $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, solvable-groups

Let $ G $ is a solvable finite group and $ M $ be a maximal subgroup of $ G $, and assume that $ G = MC $, for some cyclic subgroup $ C $. If $ M_{G} = 1 $ that $ M_{G} $ is core of $ M $ in $ G $, is$ M \cap C $ a normal subgroup of $ G $?

Comment: $M \cap C \unlhd C$, so $M \cap C = \cap_{c \in C} (M \cap C)^c \le \cap_{c \in C}M^c = M_G=1$.

Comment: It's a proof that $M \cap C = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

No: Consider the solvable group $G:=\operatorname{Aff}(\Bbb{F}_5)\cong\Bbb{F}_5\rtimes\Bbb{F}_5^{\times}$ with the maximal subgroup
$$M:=\Bbb{F}_5\rtimes\Bbb{F}_5^{\times2},$$
of affine transformations with square leading coefficient, and cyclic subgroup
$$C:=\{0\}\rtimes\Bbb{F}_5^{\times},$$
of linear transformations. Clearly $MC=G$ but we have
$$M\cap C=\{0\}\rtimes\Bbb{F}_5^{\times2},$$
which is not normal in $G$.

Comment: This does not satisfy $M_G=1$, but perhaps that condition was added after you answered the question?

Comment: @DerekHolt yes. I'm added after answerd.